# Using Firebase for chat applications does it scale?

Tags: streaming, firebase, push

Given Firebase supports realtime push for web, android and iOS, I was tempted to try it out like pub/sub type push based system. Does anyone know if the firebase works and scale to large userbase? for example million+ users of chat conversations and users accessing that data simultaneously, what would be response time as users grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase free and basic plans limit connections to 100. Their higher end plans limit connections to 10,000. That's done to prevent abuse.

From the Firebase website in case it was overlooked:
Those restrictions can be lifted though, and their Enterprise solutions can scale to millions of connections and terabytes of data

I cannot speak from personal experience with a million users but given the performance we have seen, it would be scalable to handle that.

Based on the scope of your project, I would engage them directly at support@firebase.com with your specific requirements.